# Windows Server 2008 R2 Citrix services.exe cpu and high page faults

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, citrix

After last windows updates, we have high cpu load and page faults on services.exe
aprox 2% cpu per Session... we deinstalled all windows updates done on this date , but situation is persistant.
processexplorer reveals for services.exe only ntdll as consumer ...

How to debug and resolve this issue ?

[image: services.exe cpu load] 
[image: services.exe graph] 
[image: process explorer properties]

Answer (score 0):

ntdll.dll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin is triggered when the debugger break into a process.

Can you validate the published application ? If it run fine and don't display a debugger popup to the end-user ?

I would tend to think the application you publish is no longer running ok, maybe a update on their side might help.

Comment: nope it's only published dektop, not a single application published.... this behaviour comes up after installing m$ updates... but we removed all 6 m$ updates...

Comment: @GerhardW.Recher Can you validate what cause the process then ? as like I told it's something that crashed, but that was coded with debugging runtime.It could even be a bad printer driver, so please test with a enduser connection.

Comment: as said, we only use published desktop, only ricoh drivers used and they are clean ... i suppose a hidden infection, not recognized by trendmicro officescan.

Comment: @GerhardW.Recher I agree, but even if a published desktop, I guess they use almost all the same office app ? I would test with an account without openning anything, and I would test with an account without GPO or printer. Only a thirdpart driver/app cause such error you face

Comment: i just deisabled with gpedit.msc debug only for a bulit in citrix user, rebooted machine and the debugui's and cpu load is gone!
curing the symptoms... still no glue which piece of software is triggering this .
scans with 5 antivirus products beside trendmicro ... no results !
so i'm lost in a maze ...

Comment: @GerhardW.Recher Isolate an user, no GPO to him. Check msconfig what oepn when the user start a session

Comment: we have no domain controller ... autostarts from sysinternals is also without any suspicious entries, not for administrator and not for any users ...

Comment: @GerhardW.Recher without a domain controller, and with disabled policy in gpedit, you know then it's a local group policy that trigger that.. check all setting that got applied